# Lodash: Start an Array iteration from nth index

Tags: lodash

In lodash how can I start the iteration of an Array from nth index?
For time being I am using following logic:

```
var arr = [10, 2, 67, 7, 3, 24, 90, 19, 4, 1, 8];

// I want to start iteration of this array "arr" from 4th index by using lodash's APIs.

var arr1 = _.drop(arr, 3);

_.each(arr1, function(value){   
    console.log(value) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine [slice()](https://lodash.com/docs#slice) with [each()](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach), which isn't all that different from what you're already doing:

```
_(arr)
    .slice(4)
    .each(function(item) { console.log(item); })
    .run();
// →
// 3
// 24
// 90
// 19
// 4
// 1
// 8
```

Comment: Thanks Adam for a positive Response.
Yes this logic is working fine but I want a single function.Actually I have also used "drop" & "each" and my logic is also working fine.

But I want single function that can give Answer from "arr" as following:
// 3
// 24
// 90
// 19
// 4
// 1
// 8

Comment: Why do you need a single function?

Comment: I want to reduce my code size this is only a reason.                                   Is there any single Lodash's API function available that can provide same result?

Comment: Both your current code, and the approach I suggested are pretty darn small. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Ok Thanks Adam.
Yes I know as you said.
But this is only my Curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lodash's function [`findIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs/#findIndex). Just **don't** return `true` inside the function, so it does not stop.

```js
_.findIndex(arr, function(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
}, 3);
```